# JSONPath - split object into array of single-member objects

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I need to convert a (flat) JSON object to an array of single-member objects:

JSON input:

```
{
  "field1": 123,
  "field2": 456,
  "fieldN": 789
}
```

Note that the number of members is variable - could be 1, could be 10.

Desired output:

```
[
  {"field1": 123},
  {"field2": 456},
  {"fieldN": 789}
]
```

Selecting every member with the JSONPath expression `$.[*]` gives me a flat array of the values only:

```
[
  123,
  456,
  789
]
```

I tried filtering against the "current element" via `@`, but it still just gives me the leaf values.

Is this even possible with JSONPath?

Comment: A, non good, way would be: `cat input.json | jq -c  | sed -e 's/,/},{/g' -e 's/^/[/' -e 's/$/]/' | jq`  (The final `| jq`, only if you want formatted json as output)

Comment: JSON Path is only a querying tool.  It can't do transformation.  Either combine it with other tools (like the comment above) or use something else like JMES Path.